# How could I simplify this long chain of conditional statements?

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement

I have the following enum

```
[Flags]
internal enum DataSectionFlags : uint
{
    TypeReg = 0x0,
    TypeDsect = 0x01,
    TypeNoLoad = 0x02,
    TypeGroup = 0x04,
    TypeNoPadded = 0x08,
    TypeCopy = 0x010,

    ContentCode = 0x020,
    ContentInitializedData = 0x040,
    ContentUninitializedData = 0x080,

    LinkOther = 0x0100,
    LinkInfo = 0x0200,

    TypeOver = 0x0400,

    LinkRemove = 0x0800,
    LinkComDat = 0x01000,

    NoDeferSpecExceptions = 0x04000,

    RelativeGP = 0x08000,

    MemPurgeable = 0x020000,

    Memory16Bit = 0x020000,
    MemoryLocked = 0x040000,
    MemoryPreload = 0x080000,

    Align1Bytes = 0x0100000,
    Align2Bytes = 0x0200000,
    Align4Bytes = 0x0300000,
    Align8Bytes = 0x0400000,
    Align16Bytes = 0x0500000,
    Align32Bytes = 0x0600000,
    Align64Bytes = 0x0700000,
    Align128Bytes = 0x0800000,
    Align256Bytes = 0x0900000,
    Align512Bytes = 0x0A00000,
    Align1024Bytes = 0x0B00000,
    Align2048Bytes = 0x0C00000,
    Align4096Bytes = 0x0D00000,
    Align8192Bytes = 0x0E00000,

    LinkExtendedRelocationOverflow = 0x01000000,

    MemoryDiscardable = 0x02000000,
    MemoryNotCached = 0x04000000,
    MemoryNotPaged = 0x08000000,
    MemoryShared = 0x10000000,
    MemoryExecute = 0x20000000,
    MemoryRead = 0x40000000,
    MemoryWrite = 0x80000000
}
```

I am casting a uint variable with this enum like so

```
var testVariable = (DataSectionFlags) 1610612768;
```

I have a method that processes the above variable like this

```
private static uint GetSectionProtection(DataSectionFlags characteristics)
{
    uint result = 0;

    if (characteristics.HasFlag(DataSectionFlags.MemoryNotCached))
    {
        // PageNoCache

        result |= 0x200;
    }

    if (characteristics.HasFlag(DataSectionFlags.MemoryExecute))
    {
        if (characteristics.HasFlag(DataSectionFlags.MemoryRead))
        {
            if (characteristics.HasFlag(DataSectionFlags.MemoryWrite))
            {
                // PageExecuteReadWrite

                result |= 0x40;
            }

            else
            { 
                // PageExecuteRead

                result |= 0x20;
            }

        }

        else if (characteristics.HasFlag(DataSectionFlags.MemoryWrite))
        {
            // PageExecuteWriteCopy

            result |= 0x80;
        }

        else
        {
            // PageExecute

            result |= 0x10;
        }
    }

    else if (characteristics.HasFlag(DataSectionFlags.MemoryRead))
    {
        if (characteristics.HasFlag(DataSectionFlags.MemoryWrite))
        {
            // PageReadWrite

            result |= 0x04;
        }

        else
        {
            // PageReadOnly

            result |= 0x02;
        }               
    }

    else if (characteristics.HasFlag(DataSectionFlags.MemoryWrite))
    {
        // PageWriteCopy

        result |= 0x08;
    }

    else
    {
        // PageNoAccess

        result |= 0x01;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm attempting to simplify the long chain of conditional statements inside this method but am having trouble doing so.

What would be the simplest way to write the conditional statements inside the method whilst still maintaining their functionality?

Comment: This code is pretty easy to follow. Not sure it needs to change. Shorter does not necessarily mean simpler. In fact, terse code with lots going on can be more confusing for others (or your future self) to maintain.

Comment: I see. I just thought it was bad convention to have so many nested statements

Comment: i agree with @Daniel, there's no problem with your code. as long as it is easy to understand

Comment: One of the easiest ways you can make this code more readable is to ask yourself every time you write a comment "how could I have avoided writing this comment?"  If you had `const uint PageNoCache = 0x200;` in your class , then the first line of your method is    `if (characteristics.HasFlag(DataSectionFlags.MemoryNotCached)) result |= PageNoCache;` and now you don't need a comment.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest a lookup dictionary like:

```
var sectionProtection = new Dictionary<DataSectionFlags, uint>
{
    [DataSectionFlags.TypeReg ] = 1,
    [DataSectionFlags.TypeDsect ] = 2,
    ...
    [DataSectionFlags.MemoryExecute | DataSectionFlags.MemoryRead | DataSectionFlags.MemoryWrite] = 0x40,
    ...
};
```

Note you'll need a separate entry for every combination of flags. Given such, you can then replace your function with the statement

```
var testVariable = sectionProtection[(DataSectionFlags) 1610612768];
```

or, if not every combination is defined:

```
if (sectionProtection.TryGetValue((DataSectionFlags) 1610612768, out testVariable ))
```

I consider this not only simpler to understand, faster to run, but also more correct. It is too easy to miss a combination, to have the same combination return different values, or to include the same combination twice when creating a list of `if ... else if ... else if ...` statements. If you miss a combination in a lookup dictionary you get an exception (or `TryGetValue` returns `false`). If you add the same combination to a dictionary twice you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best that I could come up with at short notice:

```
private static uint GetSectionProtection(DataSectionFlags characteristics)
{
    uint result = 0;

    if (characteristics.HasFlag(DataSectionFlags.MemoryNotCached))
    {
        // PageNoCache
        result |= 0x200;
    }

    var ladder = new KeyValuePair<DataSectionFlags[], uint>[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<DataSectionFlags[], uint>(new [] { DataSectionFlags.MemoryExecute, DataSectionFlags.MemoryRead, DataSectionFlags.MemoryWrite, }, 0x40),
        new KeyValuePair<DataSectionFlags[], uint>(new [] { DataSectionFlags.MemoryExecute, DataSectionFlags.MemoryRead, }, 0x20),
        new KeyValuePair<DataSectionFlags[], uint>(new [] { DataSectionFlags.MemoryExecute, DataSectionFlags.MemoryWrite, }, 0x80),
        new KeyValuePair<DataSectionFlags[], uint>(new [] { DataSectionFlags.MemoryExecute, }, 0x10),
        new KeyValuePair<DataSectionFlags[], uint>(new [] { DataSectionFlags.MemoryRead, DataSectionFlags.MemoryWrite, }, 0x04),
        new KeyValuePair<DataSectionFlags[], uint>(new [] { DataSectionFlags.MemoryRead, }, 0x02),
        new KeyValuePair<DataSectionFlags[], uint>(new [] { DataSectionFlags.MemoryWrite, }, 0x08),
        new KeyValuePair<DataSectionFlags[], uint>(new DataSectionFlags[] { }, 0x01),
    };

    result |= ladder.Where(x => x.Key.All(y => characteristics.HasFlag(y))).First().Value;

    return result;
}
```

---

A possibly more readable version:

```
private static uint GetSectionProtection(DataSectionFlags characteristics)
{
    uint result = 0;

    if (characteristics.HasFlag(DataSectionFlags.MemoryNotCached))
    {
        // PageNoCache
        result |= 0x200;
    }

    var ladder = new []
    {
        new { Flags = new [] { DataSectionFlags.MemoryExecute, DataSectionFlags.MemoryRead, DataSectionFlags.MemoryWrite, }, Value = (uint)0x40 },
        new { Flags = new [] { DataSectionFlags.MemoryExecute, DataSectionFlags.MemoryRead, }, Value = (uint)0x20 },
        new { Flags = new [] { DataSectionFlags.MemoryExecute, DataSectionFlags.MemoryWrite, }, Value = (uint)0x80 },
        new { Flags = new [] { DataSectionFlags.MemoryExecute, }, Value = (uint)0x10 },
        new { Flags = new [] { DataSectionFlags.MemoryRead, DataSectionFlags.MemoryWrite, }, Value = (uint)0x04 },
        new { Flags = new [] { DataSectionFlags.MemoryRead, }, Value = (uint)0x02 },
        new { Flags = new [] { DataSectionFlags.MemoryWrite, }, Value = (uint)0x08 },
        new { Flags = new DataSectionFlags[] { }, Value = (uint)0x01 },
    };

    result |= ladder.Where(x => x.Flags.All(y => characteristics.HasFlag(y))).First().Value;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Clever, but I find the original significantly more clear and readable (and thus maintainable)...

Comment: @TypeIA - Yes, I agree. What makes this interesting is that this is configurable. The `ladder` can be changed at run-time or read from a config file. But I do agree that it's not as easy to follow.

Comment: This is more *maintainable*. The KVP instantiations is a *data structure* that *clearly* associates flags; no triple nested if's needed! Comparatively, data structure always results in simpler code: 9 "result =" blocks collapse to 1 line! Modifying that if-else/if nest requires more mental energy and is necessarily more error prone than non-branching code. A 1-line comment will explain what `uint` (the value in the KV pair) is; this is an *understandability* issue, not readability. This answer is pleasantly *readable* vis-a-vis a nested control structure.